# Where to put a website's purpose?

Tags: content, about

I want my website to have a general statement of our philosophy. It would be along the lines of describing why it is important to be healthy in general and guide them to use various parts of the site.

Where would be the appropriate place for this sort of content? Is this something we put on the landing page, or perhaps in an about section or even the footer?

I want it to be accessible but not annoying.

Comment: Sorry but this is impossible to answer since there are so many variables, including UI design, website's goal, information architecture, type of site and so on. The only possible correct answer will be given by testing, everything else is just an opinion. It could even be a splash page or part of a tour! Anyways, based on your description, it looks like you might want to test prominent places rather than second level pages

Comment: If you have to *explain* the purpose, then it may be that your site needs a lot more work. Hopefully, the purpose of a site is self evident.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are pros and cons to both. I would suggest showing something on both landing page as well as in the footer/near the footer. By balancing out the contents presented in these two locations, a good level of outreach can be achieved. See my reasoning below.

**On landing page**

Obviously the first thing your visitors see. If one of your business goals is to inform the visitors of your statement of philosophy, this is the ideal spot. You can get the message across quickly as well as subtly demonstrating how important is the philosophy to you. Consider showing a concise easy to read title with a few lines of blurb. Show this version of the message only once - in the landing page - to prevent bombarding the users with the same statement over and over again. However, you'd still need a subtle reminder of the statement showing up throughout the site. This is where footer comes into play.

**In/near the footer**

Assuming you have a common footer showing up throughout the site, you can place a short version of the statement in/near the footer. Thus your statement of philosophy receives constant impression. Keeping the repeated impression in mind, you should show a less dramatic version here, the slogan or motto only perhaps. This can even be a hyperlink to a page containing detailed discussion of the topic.

Answer (score 0):

You just put the link of company profile on footer of the landing page and it opens to other page, It's common for many website to put there so that It's not annoying its core content.

Comment: Welcome to the site, @Juli. Do you have any evidence that the footer is a better location than the other options the original poster suggests?

Comment: @GrahamHerrli check it out this link https://www.orbitmedia.com/blog/website-footer-design-best-practices/ hope  it helps...

Comment: You may want to incorporate some evidence from that article directly in your post. (At the moment the post reads as just opinion.)

Comment: I think its question will have the relative answers differently and not absolute right or same from people who wanna answer this matter according to their experiences.

Answer (score 0):

You can place that in the **landing page**, something like this:

landing page structure:

- Header section
- Overview section ( sort of slider etc )
- Purpose section
- Insert another section if needed
- Footer section

There are no right or wrong answer to this, it depends on who your audience is. What kind of websites do you build.